# My normal text moves when I use the hover property in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a sort draft 'Contact Us' page and I thought I'd play around with the hover property in CSS. See my code below.

```css
.hoverinfo {
  position: static;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hoverinfo p {
  display: none;
  color: #000000;
  border: 4px;
}
.hoverinfo:hover p {
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
<div id="contact" class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="phone" class="hoverinfo">Telephone
        <p>Number</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="twitter" class="hoverinfo">Twitter
        <p>Twitter URL</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My issue at the moment is when I hover over 'Telephone' or 'Twitter', the actual text itself moves. I had a look around and people are usually saying it's because of padding, but I don't have any! This only started because I wanted to move the actual text that pops up farther to the right hand side because it was way too close to the other text when it popped up.

Comment: a lot of that movement has to do with the `margin: 20px;`. You are adding 20px margin on top and bottom when you hover. Try changing that to `margin: 0 20px;` so you only get margin on left and right.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution using `display:inline;` on the visible / hovered `<p>` item:

```css
.hoverinfo {
  position: static;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hoverinfo p {
  display: none;
  color: #000000;
}
.hoverinfo:hover p { 
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:20px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
<div id="contact" class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="phone" class="hoverinfo">Telephone
        <p>Number</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="twitter" class="hoverinfo">Twitter
        <p>Twitter URL</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm unsure what's changed in the code above other than removing the margin. I wanted the margin in because I want the text that pops up to be a bit further to the right of the other text if that makes sense!

Comment: @Herro2689 Just use `margin-right: 20px;` then if you only want margin on the right

Comment: @zgood - Thanks but that didn't do anything to the text (no margin) and also the normal text still moves when I hover.

Comment: The wrong answer had 2 upvotes after 5 seconds, but your actually working one didn't even get upvoted once. Suspicious and hillarious.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian - I changed the code to just inline and that's stopped the text moving, but the hovered text has no margin even though margin is set at 20px.

Comment: Ah, I see. I placed margin below border as above and that worked. Didn't realize that would be the difference! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to just add position absolute to p Tag on hover.

```css
.hoverinfo {
  position: static;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hoverinfo p {
  display: none;
  color: #000000;
  border: 4px;
}
.hoverinfo:hover p {
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
<div id="contact" class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="phone" class="hoverinfo">Telephone
        <p>Number</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="twitter" class="hoverinfo">Twitter
        <p>Twitter URL</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```